# is there a simple way to update a single record property in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a simple way to update a single record property in Firebase?  For example, let's say I wanted to simply update the Name property of Product id 1.  I tried the following code but this eliminated all of the other properties for Product id 1:

```
//update a product
var ciRef = dbRef.child("Product");
ciRef.update({
  1: {
    Name: "my-prod-2"
  }
});
```

Is there a simple way to configure my update command to update a single property for a record without eliminating all of the other properties?

Comment: For future problems, please indicate when you cross-post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/7ij8lb/is_there_a_simple_way_to_update_a_single_record/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update more deeply into the location that needs to be changed.  Try this instead:

```
//update a product
var ciRef = dbRef.child("Product/1");
ciRef.update({
  Name: "my-prod-2"
});
```